# Как использовать .env файлы в docker-yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Господа, не подскажите каким образом задействовать env файлы во время билда докер-компоуза? Я что-то туплю.

Вот, например, мой env_dev

```
SERVER_PORT=8081
SERVER_EXTERNAL_PORT=8082
ENVIRONMENT=development
SSO_CLIENT_SECRET=$SSO_CLIENT_SECRET_DEV
TELESCOPE_EMAIL=$TELESCOPE_EMAIL_DEV
TELESCOPE_PASSWORD=$TELESCOPE_PASSWORD_DEV
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=parking
POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER_DEV
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD_DEV
POSTGRES_DB=parking
POSTGRES_HOST=db-develop
```

Докер компоуз длинный, поэтому выложу часть :

```
parking-server-master:
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT
      - IMAGE_NAME
      - ENVIRONMENT
      - SSO_CLIENT_SECRET
      - TELESCOPE_EMAIL
      - TELESCOPE_PASSWORD
      - CONTAINER_NAME
      - POSTGRES_HOST
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        - PORT=$SERVER_PORT
        - ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
        - SSO_CLIENT_SECRET=$SSO_CLIENT_SECRET
        - TELESCOPE_EMAIL=$TELESCOPE_EMAIL
        - TELESCOPE_PASSWORD=$TELESCOPE_PASSWORD
        - POSTGRES_HOST=$POSTGRES_HOST
    ports:
      - $SERVER_EXTERNAL_PORT:$SERVER_PORT
    image: $IMAGE_NAME
    container_name: $CONTAINER_NAME
    depends_on:
      - db-master
    networks:
      - backend_master_net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что вообще возможно "прокинуть" окружение запуска сервиса композ-файла (из `environment` или `env_file`) в контекст сборки докер-образа.

Запись Вашего композ-файла типа

```
arg:
  - FOO=$BAR
```

пытается забрать данные не из окружения композ-файла, а из окружения запуска команды docker-compose. Поэтому чтобы что-то попало в аргумент FOO без использования явного присваивания в композ-файле, то можно попробовать использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
BAR=123 docker-compose build parking-server-master
```

Если имеется необходимость собирать образы через композ для разных окружений, т.е. с разными значениями аргументов сборки, то лично я пока не нашел ничего лучше чем иметь в проекте несколько композ-файлов и/или докер-файлов.

[Вот](https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/) интересная статья на эту тему окружений для докера

И не забудьте прописать [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) в самом докер-файле для каждого значения из секции args композ-файла

Answer (score 1):

Вместо:

```
environment:
  - SERVER_PORT
  - IMAGE_NAME
  - ENVIRONMENT
  - SSO_CLIENT_SECRET
  - TELESCOPE_EMAIL
  - TELESCOPE_PASSWORD
  - CONTAINER_NAME
  - POSTGRES_HOST
```

нужно:

```
 env_file:
    - .env
```

**environmnt** - используется для назначения переменных окружения "на месте", например: *SERVER_PORT=5000*. Грубо говоря определение ENV внутри файла конфигурации.

**env_file** - указывает путь к файлам откуда нужно прочитать переменные окружения.
Больше информации в [офф. документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).